# Pelican site on Netlify

Tags: netlify, pelican

I am using pelican to create myself a static site.

I'm trying to build the site in Netlify. I am using the following image in Netligy:

> Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 (default)
>   Current default build image for all new sites

And am trying to build using the command:

```
pelican
```

However I get the following error:

```
pelican: Command not found
```

I have a **runtime.txt** file with **3.5.2**

Has anyone managed to set up a site using pelican in Netlify? How do I set  up my site as continuous deployment?

Comment: Are you trying to *build* the site on Netlify, or just *serve* it? The output of the build is a bunch of HTML and other static files, you shouldn't need Pelican on the server.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Netlify does allow for python on their build servers, so pelican can be used to build a site output folder.

Comment: @user791793 Not sure your setup is compatible for the answer I gave, but there are definitely people who have used pelican for their site builds.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it. I had requirements.txt in the root when it should be in the src directory.

Comment: @user791793 where does it say requirements.txt has to be in src directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you setup everything correctly, you can use the command `make publish` and publish would be `output`. Those are the typical defaults for pelican the last time I tested it.

If you do not have a `requirements.txt` file, you can run:

```sh
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

You can include a `netlify.toml` file in your project (repository) root.

`netlify.toml`

```
[build]
  command = "make publish"
  publish = "output"
```

***Note:*** the two publish command names are not related. The makefile publish is usually a default. The `build.publish` tells Netlify where to get the site for publishing to the CDN.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it. I had requirements.txt in the root when it should be in the src directory.

Comment: Great. Glad it worked. I added the requirements note to the answer too.